# selenium opens 5 tabs, runs code on them, opens 5 more tabs without saving the information in the table of the first 5

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium and multithreading to open multiple tabs at the same time, this is so I can collect information about all the games I want. The problem is that my code doesn't work the way I want it to. My code opens 5 tabs, opens all the inserts on them opening all the information I need, and then opens the next 5 and so on until the list runs out of links. I wanted all this data after 1 round of parsing saved in a separate page for each game and add data every 10-30 seconds. I had previously made it so that all data was saved to only 1 table and it worked, but when I modified the code it stopped working. Maybe someone has encountered this problem, can you see where I made a mistake?

```
import time
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import mysql.connector

user_agent = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
headers = {'user-agent': user_agent}

def get_current_time():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return current_time

db_config = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '#',
    'database': '#'
}

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    create_database_query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bebe"
    cursor.execute(create_database_query)

    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Ошибка при создании базы данных:", error)

def parse_game(link):
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\tulen\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject4\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(5)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-collapsed="true" and contains(@class, "style_primary__1bqk9") and contains(@class, "style_marketGroup__1z6ED")]')))

    buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-collapsed="true" and contains(@class, "style_primary__1bqk9") and contains(@class, "style_marketGroup__1z6ED")]')
    for button in buttons:
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(button).click().perform()

    time.sleep(2)

    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
    live_indicator = soup.find("div", class_="style_live__3cdeN")

    if live_indicator:
        return

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "style_button-wrapper__2pKZZ")))
    other_data = soup.find_all("div", class_="style_button-wrapper__2pKZZ")

    current_time = get_current_time()

    data_list = []

    for i, row in enumerate(other_data):
        odds_name_element = row.find("span", class_="style_label__2rlQp")
        odds_name = odds_name_element.text.strip() if odds_name_element else ""
        odds_element = row.find("span", class_="style_price__3LrWW")
        odds = odds_element.text.strip() if odds_element else "Odds locked"

        if odds_name:
            data_list.append([current_time, odds_name, odds])

    table_name = link.split("/")[-2]

    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    create_table_query = f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Time VARCHAR(20),
        odds_name VARCHAR(50),
        odds VARCHAR(50),
        UNIQUE KEY `unique_odds` (`Time`, `odds_name`)
    )
    """
    cursor.execute(create_table_query)

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    # Сохранение данных в базу данных
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (Time, odds_name, odds) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.executemany(insert_query, data_list)

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    driver.quit()

    time.sleep(30)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\tulen\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject4\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.pinnacle.com/ru/esports/matchups/highlights/")

while True:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="style_metadata__DPrQU"]/div/a')))

    games = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="style_metadata__DPrQU"]/div/a')
    game_links = [game.get_attribute("href") for game in games]
    game_links = list(set(game_links))

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as executor:
        executor.map(parse_game, game_links)

    time.sleep(10)
```

I expected the code to save information for each game in a separate table in the database, every 10-30 seconds to update the data, not rewrite them, and add to the already existing, this would allow you to compare information